# Already defined function cannot use in idle?

Tags: python, function, python-idle, defined

I have a simple program that I'm trying to learn in python.   I have defined the function as such

```
>>> def area(base, height):
        return base * height /2
```

when I try to use the function as such

```
>>> area(3,4)
```

I am given this error saying that it is not defined.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
area(3,4)
NameError: name 'area' is not defined
```

Am I missing a vital step?

Comment: it seem you started working in new shell,  better to use shell where function is declared

Comment: `File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>` seems to imply you are using a brand new REPL...

Comment: Even when I type area(3,4) directly underneath it, it gives me the same error.   Is there a setting in idle that is created a new shell between lines?

Comment: Hard to believe. Might be one of the rare cases where a screenshot could help, letting us see what you're really doing.

Comment: @Kevin after entering the line `return base * height /2` press return *twice*. 1st to finish the line itself and 2nd to finish the function. Then try to call `area(3,4)` again. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error

https://ibb.co/bB439r7

Comment: @Kevin Try pressing enter *twice* after your function definition. Your function `area` has not been "finalized", if that makes sense to you. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that when you typed area(3,4) directly underneath it, you did **not** get the same error but a **syntax** error.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to restart IDLE's shell is a feature.  It clears everything without having to exit python and restart.  It's main use is automatic, when you run a file from the editor.  (The restart can be prevented with `Run Custom ...`.)

Having to end interactive compound statements with a blank line is not IDLE specific.  The following is from interactive python.  IDLE imitates this, for the same reason.

```
>>> def area():
...     return 3
... area()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    area()
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```